# Django form Data Retaliate and Display

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am getting this type of data in my template file , from forms.py . Now I want to get only data of **sql_name** field which is  `u'ag_pres` . So how I can get this data ? kindly before down vote let me know what I am doing wrong ?

`<type 'list'>: [{'sql_name': u'ag_pres', 'type': 'string', 'name': u'Ag Pres', 'map_order': 0}, {'sql_name': u'abc', 'type': 'string', 'name': u'ABC', 'map_order'`: 0}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without the rest of the view and template code, but looking at that output I think the problem is that `sql_name` is inside an object that's in a list – so not directly accessible.

You'll need to loop through the items in the list in your template to output the value of `sql_name`. You can do this with the {% for %} built-in tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for

E.g., in your template:

```
{% for item in the_list %}
    {{ item.sql_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you might have a variable with this data in it, let me call it `result`, and that you've asked for its type.

Then I can say,

```
result = [{'sql_name': u'ag_pres', 'type': 'string', 'name': u'Ag Pres', 'map_order': 0}, {'sql_name': u'abc', 'type': 'string', 'name': u'ABC', 'map_order': 0}]
```

I can see that result is a list, and I find that its length is two.

```
>>> len(result)
2
```

'sql_name' is evidently in the second item in the list, which is a dictionary.

```
>>> result[1]
{'sql_name': 'abc', 'map_order': 0, 'name': 'ABC', 'type': 'string'}
```

Then I can get the value of this item in the following way.

```
>>> result[1]['sql_name']
'abc'
```

Comment: Yes my finding are same Thanks A lot Sir